# Is there a way to pass an array to a python generic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I am doing some meta programming, and I need a way to define type hints on the fly. Is there a way to pass an array of arguments to a type hint? Something like:

```
# Some programatically generated list where I don't know the content until runtime
permitted_types = [int, str, bool, float, list, dict]

union = Union[*permitted_types]
```

The code above yields:

```
TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got [<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'dict'>]
```

Does anybody know syntax for doing this? At the moment I am reduced to the following and I hate it:

```
num_args = len(args)
if num_args == 1:
    return origin[args[0]]
elif num_args == 2:
    return origin[args[0], args[1]]
elif num_args == 3:
    return origin[args[0], args[1], args[2]]
elif num_args == 4:
    return origin[args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]]
elif num_args == 5:
    return origin[args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]]
elif num_args == 6:
    return origin[args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]]
else:
    # Raise error
```

Comment: Type hints are a concept that exist *outside* of runtime.  In other words, you must know the superset of all supported types ahead of time.  However, you *can* use things like `TypeVar` to represent [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics).

Comment: @0x5453 - They MOSTLY exist outside of runtime - certain cases cause them to persist into runtime in some forms. e.g.:
```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    obj: List[str]
    
print(Foo.__dataclass_fields__['obj'].type)
```
(Sorry about formatting) - you can see the type exists at runtime

Comment: If you don't know the contents of `permitted_types` until runtime, how is it supposed to help you verify the correctness of the code? Or else *what else do you hope to accomplish* by using type annotations?

Comment: @tofarr Yes, good point.  Dataclasses are a great example of using type hints at runtime.  The `__annotations__` attribute is another interesting example.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - the objective in this case is not to use the type hints to verify the correctness of code, but rather to help generate bindings for data marshalling / unmarshalling. (Similar to marshmallow / pydantic, but with some extra secret sauce) The type annotations then serve to verify the client code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I found the syntax by rummaging around in typing.py:

```
return Union[tuple(permitted_types)]
```

Comment: You should be aware that while this is legal *Python* syntax, it is too dynamic for any Python static type-checker to be able to understand with their current capabilities.

Comment: @AlexWaygood - thanks for the heads up - the problem I am actually trying to solve here is actually related directly to type hint processing, so most client code will be nice and type safe with the ugly hidden in a few dark corners of the codebase.