How to use subclasses in pydantic nested model?
In pydantic, I want to create a model that includes subclasses of another model.
Below, find an example.
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Action(BaseModel):
    name: str


class LogAction(Action):
    log_level: str
    timestamp: str


class Alert(BaseModel):
    id: int
    message: str
    action: Action


alert1 = Alert(
    id=1,
    message="Alert Message",
    action=LogAction(name="Error Log", log_level="ERROR", timestamp="2024-04-20T10:45:00"),
)
print(alert1)
print(alert1.model_dump())


The alert includes the attributes specific to LogAction, but on model_dump, only the attribute of the base class Action is included.
Of course I can specify action: Action | LogAction but I want action to accept any class derived from Action. Still, all attributes of the subclass should be dumped/ serialized. Is there a clever way to do this?

You can solve it by using generic with type var bounded to Action.
The disadvantage is that in json schema you will see only Action.
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError


class Action(BaseModel):
    name: str


class LogAction(Action):
    log_level: str
    timestamp: str


class AnotherAction(Action):
    something: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Action)


class Alert(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    id: int
    message: str
    action: T


alert1 = Alert(
    id=1,
    message="Alert Message",
    action=LogAction(name="Error Log", log_level="ERROR", timestamp="2024-04-20T10:45:00"),
)
print(alert1)
print(alert1.model_dump())

alert2 = Alert(
    id=1,
    message="Another Message",
    action=AnotherAction(name="another", something="123"),
)
print(alert2)
print(alert2.model_dump())



class AnotherAction2(BaseModel):  # Not inherited from Action
    something: str

try:
    alert3 = Alert(
        id=1,
        message="Another Message",
        action=AnotherAction2(something="123"),
    )
except ValidationError:
    print("alert3 validation error")


Thank you!
I have a follow-up question: How can I initialize it with the appropriate Action class when deserialization?
print(Alert(**alert1.model_dump()))
just gives a plain Action

I'm afraid in this implementation the only one way is print(Alert[LogAction](**alert1.model_dump())). I think that to make it work without specifying concrete subclass of Action you can only implement it with discriminated unions (https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions)

I found a way! I could not have done it without your solution as I didn't know about this Generic-type.

In the end, I stuck with Union:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-str-discriminators.
It's a bit tricky, but you can define them dynamically at runtime
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353207/is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-array-to-a-python-generic

Here is the answer to the follow-up-question in the comment.
It extends @YuriiMotov's answer, so that it can serialize and deserialize into the right subclass. The trick is to store the subclass name when an object is serialized.
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, field_serializer, model_validator
from rich import print


class Action(BaseModel):
    name: str


class LogAction(Action):
    log_level: str
    timestamp: str


class AnotherAction(Action):
    something: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Action)


class Alert(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    id: int
    message: str
    action: T

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def rootval(cls, values):
        if isinstance(values.get("action"), dict):
            action_type = values["action"].get("action_type")
            action_class = globals().get(action_type)
            if action_class is None:
                raise ValueError(f"Unknown action type: {action_type}")
            values["action"] = action_class(**values["action"])
        return values

    @field_serializer("action")
    def actionserializer(self, val: T):
        res = val.model_dump()
        res["action_type"] = type(val).__name__
        return res


alert1 = Alert(
    id=1,
    message="Alert Message",
    action=LogAction(name="Error Log", log_level="ERROR", timestamp="2024-04-20T10:45:00"),
)
print(alert1)
print(alert1.model_dump())

alert2 = Alert(
    id=1,
    message="Another Message",
    action=AnotherAction(name="another", something="123"),
)
print(alert2)
print(alert2.model_dump())

print(Alert(**alert1.model_dump()))

